# C# comparing alot of elements

Tags: c#

Im making a small game in Unity(using c#)

basicly what I have there is each player chooses one Damage Spell or one Shield Spell.and the thing is that the number of combinations is huge. like 100 cases. for example , shadow dmg spell will deal 0 dmg to light shield but will deal 4 dmg to Life shield(just an example) I dont need code, I just need advice, how do I handle all of it withought tons of if statements? Thank you :)

Comment: Why are you comparing them?

Comment: For example I have level 1 fire spell, and enemy has level 2 frost shield, I will do 1 dmg to him, but if he would have level 3 frost shield I would deal 0 dmg to him. so basicly every spell has a counter shield, and can coutner 1 shield(fire will counter frost, but will be countered by watter)

Comment: so now Im checking if I We have a counter or I am being countered and calculate dmg like that. but I see there will be a problem if I will add more spells.

Comment: now I have only 3 spells, so its basicly 3 instances. 1You Counter 2You are being countered and 3equal. I mean I dont know if I will ever add more than 3 spells to the game, but I still want to know how to handle this things for the future.

Comment: Even with those clarifications, I don't understand the problem. If you want to have every spell type interact in an exactly-defined way with every other spell type, you're going to have to define all of those interactions. What substitute do you see?

Answer (score 3):

If you desire a pure function like `int ComputeDamage(Type a, Type b)`, instead of expressing the combinations of `a` and `b` in code, you can encode them as data in an associative dictionary or a table.

A lookup will then be along the lines of `damageTable[a][b]` or `damageMap.get(pair(a,b))`. An immediate benefit of driving the logic via data is that it's easier to tune and get oversight over a table or mapping than it is to squint past a horde of conditional statements and possibly convoluted logic.

As an example, consider answering the rock-paper-scissors question "does A beat B":

```
    \ A  | Rock  Paper  Scissors
   B \   |
---------------------------------
    Rock | Tie   Win    Loss
   Paper | Loss  Tie    Win
Scissors | Win   Loss   Tie
```

vs.

```
if (a == b)
{
    return Tie;
}
if (a == Rock && b == Scissors ||
    a == Paper && b == Rock ||
    a == Scissors && b == Paper)
{
    return Win;
}
else
{
    return Loss;
}
```

The code approach can be compressed by leveraging symmetries in the parameters and data, but may be considered harder to interpret the effects of, while a set of data has predictable results given any combination of inputs.

If you've got a bit of a hybrid scenario where you've got some special cases but most are covered by data, you can combine a data lookup with regular logic.

Comment: So what you suggest is that I create a giant table with all possible spells and all posible shield combination and just write the data manualy, and when I need to calculate dmg, I just loop through that table?

Comment: Thank you for answering :) I thing this methood suits me perfectly

Comment: @DmitryAnashko Great to see you solved your problem! If you found this answer useful, please go ahead and [accept it](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer).

Answer (score 1):

From a programming perspective. I think matching individual items will not scale. Every unit, weapon, piece of armor, etc. should know about the different types of damage, multipliers, etc. that it can deal or absorb. The programming gets much easier and you can add new items in the future without having to be sure you got all of the mapping correctly.

Example: I'm going to use a simple example so that you don't get hung up on what a light shield vs life shield should do.

Let's say I have a spell that deals fire damage. The base shield will deal 1 unit (hit point, etc) of fire damage. As the level of the spell goes up, the amount of damage scales in some fashion too. Level 5 deals 5 units of damage.

I have two opponents. One has a fire shield. One has a basic shield.

Each shield knows what kind of damage it can take, and any special rules that may apply to that item. The shields can level up and change this multiplier as well.

I attack the opponent with the basic shield using my level 5 fire spell. His shield is a level 2 shield that absorbs 2 units of damage. My attack reduces the opponents health by 4.

I attack the opponent with the fire shield with the same level 5 spell. Her shield is a lvl 2 fire shield. The fire shield knows that it can absorb 2 units, but it also sees that the type of damage coming in is fire damage. This shield knows that it will reduce the damage by 20% (lvl 2 X 10% reduction each level) before doing to damage math. So the fire resistance reduces the incoming damage number to 4 (5 - 20%), then absorbs 2 more, resulting in my opponents health to reduce by 2. Fire shield was more effective against a fire spell.

Instead of trying to map all items, if you simply let each item know what it's special props are, you the only thing you need to worry about is calculating the amount and type of damage sent out, and how to respond to it.

You can either use distinct values like I did above, or just use multipliers at each level.

A weapon may have a base damage number (lvl 1), then a percentage multiplier for each additional level. You may have to store a value for every type of damage on every weapon. Fire spell get 10% damage boost/resist boost, 0 light boost, 0 life boost.

You can also stack these values by using a multiplier on the player level as well (if you have that). A level 8 player using a lvl 2 fire spell may do more damage than a lvl 2 player using the same lvl 2 spell.

If you go this route, no mapping required. I hope that helps.